# Using repeated-measures ANOVA to test Rater agreement

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I am looking to determine if three raters have statistically different observations of the same data, which is continuous.
For example, if the diameters of heart, X, for 20 patients were measured under 3 different techniques, X1, X2 and X3.

Since those 3 different techniques measures the same set of subjects, which is measuring the same variable in different conditions, I am thinking to use a one-way repeated measures ANOVA to compare all three at the same time.
However, I saw some posts that using simple one-way ANOVA might be more suitable.

Would it be more suitable to use the repeated ANOVA?
Also, is it possible to get the ICC for intra class and inter class for this case?